# Autorestart services after crash in rhel 6

Tags: rhel, chkconfig

How to implemented this without systemd (chkconfig, etc..)?

I would like to restart PostgreSQL, Mongod and RabbitMQ.

Comment: Please add to the question which service Apache, BIND?

Comment: PostgreSQL, Mongod, RabbitMQ

Answer (score 2):

To do automatic recovery of services, you can use `monit`. It is a rather lightweight and easy service to use.

To install it in Debian do:

```
sudo apt-get install monit
```

[How To Install and Configure Monit](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-monit)

As for configuring it, you edit `/etc/monit/monitrc` and the restart the service.

For instance, to monitor whether the daemon is running, and if the service is answering in the corresponding ports, and configure automatic recovery for PostgreSQL,  RabbitMQ  and mongoDB:

> ```
> check process postgres with pidfile /var/postgres/postmaster.pid
>    group database
>    start program = "/etc/init.d/postgresql start"
>    stop  program = "/etc/init.d/postgresql stop"
>    if failed unixsocket /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432 protocol pgsql 
>       then restart
>    if failed host 192.168.1.1 port 5432 protocol pgsql then restart
>
> check host mongodb with address localhost
>     start program = "/usr/bin/sudo /opt/database/mongo/bin/mongod"
>     stop program = "/usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/pkill -f mongod"
>     if failed port 28017 protocol HTTP
>         request /
>         with timeout 10 seconds
>         then start
>
> check process rabbitmq-server with pidfile /var/run/rabbitmq.pid  
>    group rabbitmq  
>    start program "/etc/init.d/rabbitmq-server start"  
>    stop program "/etc/init.d/rabbitmq-server stop"  
>    if failed port 5672 type tcp then restart  
>    if 3 restarts within 3 cycles then timeout
> ```

For more services, see: [Monit wiki](https://mmonit.com/wiki/Monit/ConfigurationExamples)

Monit also allows you to send an email in rules, and acting in load of the server. I would advise anyone to investigate it better.

Answer (score 1):

RedHat 6 uses *upstart* as the init system.

You need to create a proper init definition in `/etc/init` (note: NOT `/etc/init.d`).

eg (but may need debugging) `/etc/init/myservice`

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [S016]

respawn
exec /code/to/program
```

The `respawn` value will cause `program` to restart if it terminates.